# PHP sorting a list of non-empty groups first, then empty groups

Tags: php, mysql

Given two tables:

```
item_to_group ---> contain item_id , user_to_group_id
user_to_group ---> contain user_to_group_id , user_id, // other not relevant columns like group name...
```

Here my mysql code:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM item_to_group x 
WHERE x.user_to_group_id = u.user_to_group_id) as tots
FROM  user_to_group u
WHERE u.user_id = // [ USERID HERE ]
ORDER BY  u.user_to_group_id DESC, tots DESC
```

I'm trying to display a list of groups, where at the top I have the groups with items in them, then the empty groups.

Imagine these groups like wishlists of items in a ecommerce. As a user I can build multiple groups.

eg.
currently I display

```
group 99 contains 2 items
group 98 contains 0 items // <--- empty
group 97 contains 5 items
group 96 contains 1 items
group 94 contains 0 items // <--- empty
group 93 contains 9 items
group 92 contains 3 items
```

but i want to display

```
group 99 contains 2 items
group 97 contains 5 items
group 96 contains 1 items
group 93 contains 9 items
group 92 contains 3 items
-------------------------
group 98 contains 0 items
group 94 contains 0 items
```

So I'd like to display the groups that are not empty first, chronologically (i don't store a timestamp but the group id should suffice i guess) THEN   all the rest of the list of empty groups.

The problem here is that if I sort by id THEN totsi don't get the result I want.
I hope I am clear.

Comment: Can you add a sample output? I am not clear about what sorting you want. Why would you sort by id first? And where does *chronologically* fit into it?

Comment: @lserni ok i added the example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort on an additional column in the very first place of your `ORDER BY` clause (to make it most relevant). You cannot sort on `tots` directly, because that would break the ordering on `user_to_group_id`. Thus you need to map all `tots` values other than 0 to a a single value — e.g. 1. This can be done using `CASE`, giving the following `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN tots = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
       , u.user_to_group_id DESC
       , tots DESC
```

Now, those having `tots` <> 0, will be ranked first, then those where `tots` = 0. The remaining sorting is the same.

If you'd like to learn more about `CASE` have a look at an article I wrote here: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case